# Chronology in Karaite selicha

Tags: tanach, prayer-book, selichot, non-rabbinic-judaism

In a Karaite siddur from 1527-9 ([link](https://www.nli.org.il/he/books/NNL_ALEPH001103403/NLI), pg. 514), in the section of selichot, there's one selicha that's similar to the rabbinical selicha "מי שענה ל...הוא יעננו". In this case, it's "כשענית ל...עננו". Like the rabbinical one, it features prominent people from the Tanach and it's organized in chronological order, except for two lines:

[image: Picture of the relevant portion from the siddur]

As can be seen, after Yesha'ayahu comes Eliyahu and after him, Elisha, though both lived many years before Yesha'ayahu. After Elisha, the order goes back to the correct chronological order. By comparison, two selichot back there's the selicha "זכר...וסלח לנו" which also features people from the Tanach, but there Eliyahu and Elisha come before Yesha'ayahu (and Chizkiyahu isn't there) (though on the other hand, Ezra comes after Nechemiah).

Is there any reason for this change in the order or is it just a mistake?

(to clarify, my question is only about the Eliyahu and Elisha part).

Comment: Is this "out-of-order" preserved in contemporaneous or modern Karaite siddurim?

Comment: Isn't Isaiah a contemporary of Hezekiah in the previous line?

Comment: Ezra after Nechemiah may be correct chronologically, according to some scholars

Comment: @magicker72 Still looking through other ones. So far haven't found this selicha anywhere else.